# Finding the area of some specific graph color in a 3D graph

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d, area

I have a graph (and its raw data) as shown below.

[image]

The axis in the graph is in cm.
I want to know the area of deep blue area in this graph (the answer should be like 20 sq.cm. or something like that).
Is there any way to find it?

Comment: What exact shades of blue count as "deep blue" for you?

Comment: I also have the raw data as a matrix.
I found that the deepest blue has value in order of 10^-8.
The distance between any value in that matrix is 1 cm.
Can I find the area of the deepest blue one from this information?

Comment: And what is this graph - is it a color image that you're just displaying, or is it scalar data that you're displaying with a colormap? It looks like the latter, displayed with the `jet` colormap, but I might be wrong.

Comment: The graph is a top-viewed of the below graph. It is a 3D graph. 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/153995/%E0%B8%88%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%A0%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%9E%E0%B8%AB%E0%B8%99%E0%B9%89%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%88%E0%B8%AD%202557-04-22%20%E0%B8%93%2019.40.06.png

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you literally mean only the deepest shade of blue, then that corresponds to the minimum of your data. You can find that with `minval = min(mydata(:));`.

Once you have the minimum value, select points that are equal to that value with `minvals = mydata == minval;`. Note that this will only collect elements that are exactly equal to your deepest blue, in a floating point sense. If you didn't literally mean only the deepest shade of blue, you might want to consider selecting all points that are within some threshold of the minimum value instead. Finally count them with `total = sum(minvals(:));`.

Then multiply the number of points by a value representing the area of each point in cm2.